# How to avoid error of JavaScript date formatting

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using the DHTMLX Scheduler in my web app and want to get the data for each event and found a way to do it with *scheduler._events* which returns this:

```
1581498064943: {…}
​​
_eday: 2    ​​
_end_date: undefined    ​​
_first_chunk: true    ​​
_last_chunk: true    ​​
_length: 1    ​​
_sday: 1    ​​
_sorder: 0   ​​
_sweek: 0    ​​
_timed: true    ​​
end_date: Date Tue Jan 02 2018 00:05:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)    ​​
event_length: ""    ​​
event_pid: ""    ​​
id: 1581498064943    ​​
rec_pattern: ""
​​rec_type: ""    ​​
start_date: Date Tue Jan 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) ​​
text: "New event"
```

the problem is when I convert it into a string to store it as a JSON later, JavaScript converts dates into iso 8601 and loses a day in the conversion:

```
"1581498064943": {
        "start_date": "2018-01-01T23:00:00.000Z",
        "end_date": "2018-01-01T23:05:00.000Z",
        "text": "New event",
        "id": 1581498064943,
        "_timed": true,
        "_sday": 1,
        "_eday": 2,
        "_length": 1,
        "_sweek": 0,
        "_sorder": 0,
        "_first_chunk": true,
        "_last_chunk": true,
        "event_pid": "",
        "event_length": "",
        "rec_pattern": "",
        "rec_type": ""
```

> 2018-01-02 becomes 2018-01-01

Comment: Because letter "Z" in ISO-8601 means Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) and it is GMT+0000. It's the same time, in other time-zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better try with Unix epoch seconds format to resolve this issue.

```js
const now = Date.now(); // Unix timestamp in milliseconds
console.log( now );
```

Once you convert this you can retrieve the same exact time based on your local region specification.

```js
var utcSeconds = 1581501372817/1000;
var d = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
d.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: thank you ! i'll use that it is more relevant in my case ^^

Answer (score 1):

It's not reducing oneday. It's because of your timeZone.
check the following code.

```
var x= new Date("Date Tue Jan 02 2018 00:05:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)")

x.toISOString()

y = new Date(x)
```

You will get the initial date again. So, to use it from the JSON again you need that ISOstring to be converted again